# Feature selection using genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have  taken a data set of total 140 images out of which 100 (50 normal and 50 abnormal) images are used for training of classifier and 40 (20 normal and 20 abnormal) images for testing purpose.

I have used intensity based (Wavelet transform, Symmetry), shape based (area, perimeter circularity) and texture based (Energy, Entropy, Contrast, Correlation, Inverse difference moment)as feature set. Now i want to reduce this feature set using genetic algorithm.

In the research paper the fitness function is given as (0.05*number)+Accuracy+Sensitivity+Specificity 
where number is a coefficient equal to the number of not selected features.
How i will know accuracy, sensitivity and specificity before applying to classifier???

Comment: Please reopen the question as i have made it more problem specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you assign a number to every feature, like so:

```
1. Energy
2. Entropy
3. Contrast
4. Circularity
5. Wavelet coefficients
6. Symmetry
7. Correlation
8. Inverse difference moment
```

The feature subset can be represented as a binary string "f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8" where fi is a `0` or `1`, indicating the corresponding feature is included (`1`) in or excluded (`0`) from the subset.

For example, `00000101` would mean:

```
Energy: 0 (don't include)
Entropy: 0 (don't include)
Contrast: 0 (don't include)
Circularity: 0 (don't include)
Wavelet coefficients: 0 (don't include)
Symmetry: 1 (include)
Correlation: 0 (don't include)
Inverse difference moment: 1 (include)
```

Comment: I got your point.. but like this how many strings i have to consider.. do i have to check the fitness function values for all the strings??

Comment: No, that's where the genetic algorithm kicks in. You initialize a population (say 10 individuals) of random strings, then you iterate evolution: recombination & mutation, selection. Until you get something that fits well enough (stop/halt criterium).

Comment: okay.. but at the end also where stop criterion is met, i will have a population size of 10.. so which string is to be chosen as final feature set among them?? how to select the fitness function??

Comment: The one that has the highest fitness.